# How to get PyCharm to display progressbar while running pytest?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I use pytest and have a test that takes a very long time. 
So I added a progress bar with [progressbar2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2).

```
import progressbar
from time import sleep


def test_progressbar_bug():
    with progressbar.ProgressBar() as bar:
        for i in bar(range(10)):
            sleep(1)
```

Running this in a terminal with `pytest -s` gives me a nice test output with a progress bar that updates as time passes.

However, if I try to run this from within PyCharm with a pytest configuration (and `-s` as option) I just get an empty output. 
Only after the test is finished the complete progress bar appears.

I also tried to create my own progress display with `sys.stdout` without any success in PyCharm's integrated pytest.

```
from time import sleep
import sys


def test_progress_bug():
    for i in range(10):
        sys.stdout.write("\rProgress: %3d" % (i * 100 / 10.) + "%")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
```

What do I have to do to display a progress bar that shows the progress of a single test when running pytests in PyCharm?

**Edit:**
I don't really like my current workaround - which is running this as a normal python configuration - because I don't get the fancy test overview of PyCharm:

**Test.py**

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system("pytest -s")
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Just install "progressbar2" lib and it will work